# Laravel Blade @include after @section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Why does Blade includes goes before sections in the rendered output the tested code shown below? Is there a way to put after or the middle of sections?

```
// Specify the filename of the layout (without extension)
@extends('layout')

// The rest of the code of the view template
// Opening content section
@section('content')
  // The content that will be injected in the layout replacing “@yield(‘content’)”
  This is the home pagevvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
// Closing content section
@stop


@section('content')
  <p>This is just Content</p>
@stop

@section('moreContent')
  <p>This is More Content</p>
@stop

@section('evenMoreContent')
  <p>This is Even More Content</p>
@stop

@include('navigation')
```

Comment: Try putting the `@include` _inside_ a section, maybe even it's own section if necessary. Or just include it from inside your master layout rather than any extending blade templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I see no way to do that, and as you are extending a template the only thing that is being rendered is the `layout` with the sections you define.

If you want to change the order in the output, the `layout` file is where you can do this.

You should edit the extended template. You can add another section in the `template` file (`@yield('naveigation')`) and the define the `navigation` section later.

In this file:

```
@section('navigation')
  @include('navigation')
@stop
```

And in `layout.blade.php`

```
Layout
<br>
Nav:
<br>
@yield('navigation')
<br>
Content:
<br>
@yield('content')
```